# Weird reflections on my mesh

Tags: reflection

this is happening when i render, anyone know why this might be happening? Eevee render

Blend file here https://www.dropbox.com/s/6m4h2ea6lnmoeqg/Ladybug%20A7%20Foro.blend?dl=0

Thanks

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: Hi Chris, here is the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/6m4h2ea6lnmoeqg/Ladybug%20A7%20Foro.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sphere.004 and sphere.005 are z-fighting. They are of the same size and on the same position.

So either turn on both (hide in viewport, hide in render) here for sphere4:

[image] and both off for sphere5 or the other way around, but not for both.

Comment: So simple Thanks Bro!!

Comment: You are welcome